# What are the differences between MOQ and AutoFixture?

Tags: unit-testing, mocking, moq, autofixture, automocking

I have a fair amount of experience using MOQ, while I've recently have stumbled into AutoFixture. What are the differences between these frameworks?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The [FAQ](https://github.com/AutoFixture/AutoFixture/wiki/FAQ) explains the difference. In short

> AutoFixture uses Reflection to create 'well-behaved' instances of public types. It auto-generates instances of other types if necessary to fill in arguments for a constructor, and also assigns values to public writable properties. In essence, it simply uses the requested type's public API to instantiate and populate it. It doesn't do anything that you, as a developer, couldn't do manually - it just does it for you automatically.
>
> In contrast, most Dynamic Mock libraries derive from known types to override the behavior of virtual members. Their purpose is to perform Behavior Verification of the System Under Test (SUT).

You can [combine AutoFixture with Moq to turn it into an automocking container](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/08/19/AutoFixtureAsAnAutomockingContainer.aspx).