# Unit Test - What is difference between AutoFixture Stub, Expect and RhinoMock Stub, Expect?

Tags: rhino-mocks, autofixture

I see a lot of people using RhinoMock with AutoFixture for unit testing. With RhinoMock we can GenerateMock or GenerateStub a class and then Stub or Expect something happen on that class but with AutoFixture we can do the same by Freeze or Create a class then Stub or Expect a method will be called.
So the what is difference between those? Why we need to use RhinoMock with AutoFixture?

Comment: You write that with AutoFixture, you can Stub or Expect. Can you give an example?

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5786628/what-are-the-differences-between-moq-and-autofixture